# Given a monotonically increasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ can we infer $a_k \leq a_{n_k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically increasing sequence. This means that for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
n < m \implies a_n \leq a_m \tag{1}
\end{align*}
If $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is an arbitrary subsequence of $\{a_n\}$, then $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is monotonically increasing, as well.

Since the sequence $\{n_k\}$ consisting of the indices of $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is strictly increasing, we know that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}: k \leq n_k$.

**Question**

Since $k \leq n_k$ I am wondering if I can immediately infer from $(1)$ that $a_k \leq a_{n_k}$ since both sequences are monotonically increasing.

This seems reasonable to me: If $k = n_k$, then $a_k = a_{n_k}$. If $k < n_k$, then $a_k \leq a_{n_k}$ seems to follow from $(1)$.

Is this inference valid?

Comment: Sure. It's fine.

Comment: Since $k \le n_k$ it is immediate that $a_k \le a_{n_k}$ by definition of monotonically increasing.